# Suppose for some $x, y \in G, xZ(G) = yZ(G)$, then there is $g \in G$ such that $xg = y$

Tags: group-theory

> This question popped up while watcing an online lecture of Group Theory Module of my university. And I couldn't come up with better title so please allow me rather generic title.

Could you help me with understanding the following statement?

### Statement

Suppose for some $x, y \in G, xZ(G) = yZ(G)$, then there is $g \in G$ such that $xg = y$

### My question

The lecturer said that "since $y$ lies in the same left coset as $x$ this holds.". But I could only think about $xg = yg$ so I don't know why $xg = y$ holds true.

Comment: Not following.  For any $x,y\in G$ we have $x(x^{-1}y)=y$ so what's the problem?

Comment: I see! I didn't see that formulatoin of $g$!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does $xZ(G) = yZ(G)$ mean? It means that the set $xZ(G)$ and $yZ(G)$ are equal as sets. In other words, any element of $xZ(G)$ is an element of $yZ(G),$ and vice versa.

Now, we know that the identity $e$ of $G$ is always in the center $Z(G).$ So, $yZ(G)$ contains the element $y \cdot e = y.$ Since $y$ is an element of $yZ(G)$ and we have $xZ(G) = yZ(G),$ $y$ must be an element of $xZ(G)$ as well.

The elements of $xZ(G)$ are of the form $xg,$ where $g$ is an element of $Z(G).$ So the fact that $y$ is in $xZ(G)$ means that $y = xg$ for some $g \in Z(G)$, as claimed.

Comment: Oh, this is rather new perspective from others! Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

$xZ(G)=yZ(G)$ means

$xh_1=yh_2$ for some $h_1, h_2\in Z(G)$

Thus

$x(h_1h_2^{-1})=y$

Taking $g:= h_1h_2^{-1}\in Z(G)$ you get

$xg=y$

Comment: Neat answer!! Thank you!

Comment: @Rowing0914 thank you 